# iphone Development - data persistance UI

Tags: ios, iphone, string

I have a UILabel that is modified while using my app.
I want the text of this UILabel to be saved even after I close the app.

What's the easiest way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the content when the app is about to quit.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:label.text forKey:@"label"];
}
```

And when you create the label, use the saved text.

```
label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"label"];
```

Answer (score 1):

[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will help you with this !

Watch this tutorial on how to use NSUserDefaults for storing/ saving data - [Save Data In Your iPhone App Using NSUserDefaults Tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=235)